# Possibility to set min_wait/max_wait per task or something similar?

Tags: locust

I am tying to simulate a specific behavior, where one api calls gets executed every 8 seconds and another every 24 seconds. Locust has a possibility to set min_wait and max_wait for the whole task_set. Is there was way to set it per task or to prevent the task from being executed unless given time has pass by in a safe way or to schedule the each on task its specific interval?

Example:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

class Paint(TaskSet):

  def on_start(self):
    self.login()

  def login(self):
    data = {'username': "paint", 'password': 'bucket'}
    self.auth = self.client.post('/auth', data)

  @task(1)
  def get_red(self):
    min_wait = 8000
    max_wait = 8000
    self.client.get("/red", headers=self.auth.request.headers['Cookie'])

  @task(1)
  def get_blue(self):
    min_wait = 24000
    max_wait = 24000
    self.client.get("/blue", headers=self.auth.request.headers['Cookie'])

class PaintBucket(HttpLocust):
  task_set = Paint
```

Comment: If you want this sort of behavior, Locust isn't really a good fit - the fundamental design principle that Locust has (simulating user behavior) doesn't really match this type of action. If you want to use Locust still you could make one task where you explicitly have these wait times built in but Locust isn't really the same paradigm as what you want to do.

Comment: I am aware that out of the box locust is not quite what I am looking for. I am still looking for a way to go around those limitations.

Answer (score 1):

As it was commented already, this is not how Locust is designed, but there is a way to work it around. You can wait in the task instead of between tasks. Based on your example:

```python
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task
from random import randint


class Paint(TaskSet):

    def on_start(self):
        self.login()

    def login(self):
        data = {'username': "paint", 'password': 'bucket'}
        self.auth = self.client.post('/auth', data)

    @task(1)
    def get_red(self):
        min_wait = 8000
        max_wait = 8000
        self.client.get("/red", headers=self.auth.request.headers['Cookie'])
        self._sleep(randint(min_wait, max_wait))

    @task(1)
    def get_blue(self):
        min_wait = 24000
        max_wait = 24000
        self.client.get("/blue", headers=self.auth.request.headers['Cookie'])
        self._sleep(randint(min_wait, max_wait))


class PaintBucket(HttpLocust):
    task_set = Paint
    min_wait = 0
    max_wait = 0
```

Of course if you always want the same wait time, you can just specify that instead of the min/max/random:

```python
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task


class Paint(TaskSet):

    def on_start(self):
        self.login()

    def login(self):
        data = {'username': "paint", 'password': 'bucket'}
        self.auth = self.client.post('/auth', data)

    @task(1)
    def get_red(self):
        wait = 8000
        self.client.get("/red", headers=self.auth.request.headers['Cookie'])
        self._sleep(wait)

    @task(1)
    def get_blue(self):
        wait = 24000
        self.client.get("/blue", headers=self.auth.request.headers['Cookie'])
        self._sleep(wait)


class PaintBucket(HttpLocust):
    task_set = Paint
    min_wait = 0
    max_wait = 0
```

Comment: Interesting, will try it out.